# how I can use indicator for time where hour and minute are in different columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I want to have 3 indicator

Indicator, 1 if trip starts in AM peak: 8:00 –9:59

Indicator, 1 if trip starts in PM peak: 16:00 –17:59

Indicator, 1 if trip starts midday: 10:00 –15:59

I have hours and minutes in different columns

```
 ARR_HR        ARR_MIN
    16              30
    10              0
    11              5
```

how I can do that?

So the out put must be

```
AM pick   PM pick    midday
   0        1          0
   0        0          1
   0        0          1
```

Comment: Please sshow the expected output

Comment: @akrun Plz see edit

Comment: `library(dplyr); library(hms); df %>% mutate(arr = hms(hours = ARR_HR, minutes = ARR_MIN), am_peak = between(arr, as.hms("08:00:00"), as.hms("09:59:00")), pm_peak = between(arr, as.hms('16:00:00'), as.hms('17:59:00')), midday = between(arr, as.hms('10:00:00'), as.hms('15:59:00')))`

Comment: How do you know `ARR_HR == 4` is PM? Why not 4AM?

Answer (score 1):

From the name of the column `ARR_HR` it seems that it would be hour of the day which would be always an integer. You could use `cut` for this. The benefit of this is you can keep on increasing `breaks` with new `labels` easily.

```
get_levels <- cut(df$ARR_HR, breaks = c(8, 10, 16, Inf), 
              labels = c("AM_Pick", "Midday", "PM_Pick"), right = FALSE)

df[levels(get_levels)] <- t(sapply(get_levels, function(x) 
                          as.integer(levels(get_levels) %in% x)))

df
#  ARR_HR ARR_MIN AM_Pick Midday PM_Pick
#1     16      30       0      0       1
#2     10       0       0      1       0
#3     11       5       0      1       0
```

If you also have minutes, you need convert the `ARR_HR` and `breaks` to `POSIXct` values and use.

---

A more tedious approach would be to check the range for each break. The downside of this is it will keep on growing the more breaks you add.

```
df$ARR_HR1 = as.POSIXct(as.character(df$ARR_HR), format = "%H")

transform(df,
   AM_pick = as.integer(ARR_HR1 >= as.POSIXct("08:00", format = "%H:%M") & 
                        ARR_HR1 <= as.POSIXct("09:59", format = "%H:%M")),
   PM_pick =  as.integer(ARR_HR1 >= as.POSIXct("16:00", format = "%H:%M") & 
                        ARR_HR1 <= as.POSIXct("17:59", format = "%H:%M")), 
   midday =  as.integer(ARR_HR1 >= as.POSIXct("10:00", format = "%H:%M") & 
                        ARR_HR1 <= as.POSIXct("15:59", format = "%H:%M")))
```

Comment: Why not still use `cut` with the decimal versions? The `breaks=` don't have to be integers - `cut(
  as.POSIXct(do.call(paste, dat), format="%H %M", tz="UTC"),
  as.POSIXct(c("08:00","10:00","16:00","18:00"), format="%H:%M", tz="UTC"),
  right=FALSE, labels=labs
)` or something similar.